# uci - how to revert all unstaged changes

Tags: openwrt

[`uci`](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci) documentation says:

> All "`uci set`", "`uci add`", "`uci rename`" and "`uci delete`" commands are staged into a temporary location and written to flash at once with "`uci commit`".

If I get it right, you first run some commands like the ones mentioned above and to make the changes be written to the configuration files you run `uci commit`. For example, let's say I have done the following changes...

```
root@OpenWrt:~# uci changes
network.vlan15.ifname='eth1.15'
network.vlan15.type='bridge'
network.vlan15.proto='static'
network.vlan15.netmask='255.255.255.0'
network.vlan15.ipaddr='192.168.10.0'
```

...but I don't want to continue and commit them. Is there an easy way to revert all staged changes and avoid doing it one by one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a command to revert all staged changes

```
revert  <config>[.<section>[.<option>]]     Revert the given option, section or configuration file.
```

So, in your case, it should be

```
uci revert network.vlan15
```

See https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/base-system/uci

Answer (score 5):

This should be possible by the following command:

```
root@firlefanz:~# rm -rf /tmp/.uci/
```

Answer (score 2):

This one-liner should do the trick:

```
uci changes | sed -rn 's%^[+-]?([^=+-]*)([+-]?=.*|)$%\1%' | xargs -n 1 uci revert
```

tl;dr The sed command extracts the option names from the staged changes. The xargs command executes the revert command for every extracted option.

Now let's have a deep dive into everything:

`uci changes` prints the prepared changes which are then piped to the sed command.

The sed opton `-r` enables extended regular expressions and `-n` suppress automatic printing of pattern matches.

The sed command `s` is used to do a search and replace and `%` is used as separation character for the search and replace term.

The uci change lines have different formats.

Removed configuration options are prefixed with `-`.
Added configuration options are prefixed with `+`
Changed options don't have a prefix.

To match the prefixes `[+-]?` is used. A question mark means, that one of the characters in the square brackets can be matched optional.

The option name will be matched with the pattern `[^=+-]*`. This regex has the meaning of any number of characters as long as the character is not one of `=+-`.
It is inside round brackets to mark it as group to reuse it later.

The next pattern ([+-]?=.*|) is also a pattern group. There are two different groups spitted by the pipe.
The second part is the easy one and means no character at all. This happens when a uci option is deleted.
The fist part means that the character `=` can optional prepended with `+` or `-`. After the `=` can be one or more characters which is indicated by `.*`. `=<value>` happens on added configuration. The prepending of `-` or `+` indicates the value is removed from the list or added to the list if the option is a list.

In the replace pattern the whole line is replaced with the first group by its reference `\1`. In other words: only the option name is printed.

All the option names are then send to xargs. With option `-n  1` xargs execuse `uci revert <option_name>` for every `option_name` send by sed.

This are some examples for the different formats of the `uci changes` output:

```
-a
+b='create new option with this value'
c='change an existing option to this value'
d+='appended to list'
e-='removed from list'
```

The extraced option names will be the following:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

`xargs -n 1`  will then executed the following commands:

```
uci revert a
uci revert b
uci revert c
uci revert d
uci revert e
```

This is the whole magic of the one-liner.

Comment: complex one-liner, i suggest you to edito your question and explain the single parts of the command

Comment: I have added a brief explanation as suggested by @enneppi.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a `uci` command to revert all uncommitted changes, but you can probably parse the output of the `uci changes` command with some shell scripting to achieve the desired result. Here is an example script:

```sh
#!/bin/ash

# uci-revert-all.sh
# Revert all uncommitted uci changes

# Iterate over changed settings
# Each line has the form of an equation, e.g. parameter=value
for setting in $(uci changes); do

    # Extract parameter from equation
    parameter=$(echo ${setting} | grep -o '^\(\w\|[._-]\)\+')

    # Display a status message
    echo "Reverting: ${parameter}"

    # Revert the setting for the given parameter
    uci revert "${parameter}"
done
```

A simpler alternative might be to use the `uci revert <config>` syntax, e.g.:

```sh
#!/bin/ash

# uci-revert-all.sh
# Revert all uncommitted uci changes

for config in /etc/config/*; do
    uci revert $(basename ${config})
done
```

Both of these approaches worked well for me on a router running LEDE 4.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another short one-liner to revert ***ALL*** unstaged changes (as per the question):

```
for i in /etc/config/* ; do uci revert ${i##*/} ; done
```

Note that this reverts all changes for *every* config file.

@BMC has suggested an improvement: only reverting changes for files that have been modified since last boot:

```
for i in /tmp/.uci/* ; do uci revert ${i##*/} ; done
```

(FYI, this uses [posix parameter expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02)'s "Remove Largest Prefix Pattern".)

Comment: Don't u mean `/tmp/.uci/*` ? `/etc/config/` does not store the unstaged changes.

Comment: "Don't u mean `/tmp/.uci/*`?" No, I meant `/etc/config/*`. I simply wanted to iterate over every config file and revert the changes for each file being iterated over. "`/etc/config/` does not store the unstaged changes." Correct, and I know that it doesn't. Your suggestion leads to a more efficient solution -  iterating over the files in `/tmp/.uci/*` means only iterating over config files that have been modified since last boot (rather than iterating of every config file). Your improvement may be minimal, but it's an improvement nonetheless!